# Jetpack Compose LazyColumn reverse display

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

native composable column with elements a, b and c:

a

b

c

how can you reverse arrangement to:

c

b

a

in android jetpack compose

Comment: Reverse the list that has the items you're passing to the column composable

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `LazyColumn's` `reverseLayout` parameter if you want to preserve your collection's structure while having a reversed display.

Say you have these items.

```
val items = listOf("Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Dogs", "Eggs", "Fruits")

ItemList(items = items)
```

Just set `LazyColumn's` `reverseLayout` to true

```
@Composable
fun ItemList(items: List<String>) {

    LazyColumn(
        reverseLayout = true
    ) {
        items(items) { item ->
            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .height(80.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .border(BorderStroke(Dp.Hairline, Color.Gray)),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = item
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]